# writing batch file is different from writing command in the prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I thought those were the exact same thing, except, in batch file you put in the commands and it will act like a function that does all the commands written in the file.

So if I put this command:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do tesseract %i %i.txt
```

where tesseract is a program that converts jpg files into text files, it works fine. ( `tesseract input.jpg output.txt`)

But if I write that exact same line into batch file, it wouldn't work saying 'i was unexpected this time.'

```
@echo off
for %i in (*.jpg) do tesseract %i %i.txt
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a batch file, you have to double the `%` sign:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.jpg) do tesseract %%i %%i.txt
```

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, it does this because a single percent sign is read as nothing, so "%i" would be read as "i". This would cause the "i was not expected at this time." error message. However, a double percent sign is interpreted as a single. To prove this you could put `echo % %%` into a batch file and watch the results.